# Sorted insert on a doubly linked list (HackerRank)

Tags: java, programming-challenge, linked-list

I've decided to do a simple linked list question to brush up my Java & CS.

---

This is the solution for

> Given a reference to the head of a doubly-linked list and an integer,
>   \$data\$ , create a new DoublyLinkedListNode object having data value
>   \$data\$
>   and insert it into a sorted linked list while maintaining the sort.
>   [Full question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-into-a-sorted-doubly-linked-list/problem)

```
   /*
     * For your reference:
     *
     * DoublyLinkedListNode {
     *     int data;
     *     DoublyLinkedListNode next;
     *     DoublyLinkedListNode prev;
     * }
     *
     */
    static DoublyLinkedListNode sortedInsert(DoublyLinkedListNode head, int data) {
        DoublyLinkedListNode nodeToInsert = new DoublyLinkedListNode(data);
        if (head == null) return nodeToInsert;
        DoublyLinkedListNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            if (data < current.data && current.prev == null) {
                current.prev = nodeToInsert;
                nodeToInsert.next = current;
                return nodeToInsert;
            }
            if (data >= current.data && current.next == null) {
                current.next = nodeToInsert;
                nodeToInsert.prev = current;
                break;
            }
            if (data >= current.data && data <= current.next.data) {
                DoublyLinkedListNode temp = current.next;
                current.next = nodeToInsert;
                nodeToInsert.prev = current;
                temp.prev = nodeToInsert;
                nodeToInsert.next = temp;
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        return head;
    }
```

This passes all test cases.

Comment: Since you're brushing up, if this were real production code, I'd ding you pretty hard on your lack of Javadoc comments.  Get a copy of *Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch and read his advice on proper in-code documentation.

Comment: @markspace yes comment in my code above is kind of weired. :( It came with the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the main problem with your solution is readability. It took me some time to understand what exactly you're doing to solve a **Hackerrank** task.

**Simplify Code**

For instance, consider the following block of yours:

```
...
if (data < current.data && current.prev == null) {
     current.prev = nodeToInsert;
     nodeToInsert.next = current;
     return nodeToInsert;
}
...
```

Doing it in a `while` loop is a bit confusing as you can directly compare `data` with `head.data` - as per problem statement the list is sorted and so the smallest element is in the current head. Move it out of the loop. Additionally, remove `current.prev == null` as the head is the first element by definition.

```
if (data < head.data) {
    head.prev = nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert.next = head;
    return nodeToInsert;
}
```

Another block that can be simplified is:

```
if (data >= current.data && current.next == null) {
    current.next = nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert.prev = current;
    break;
}
```

Here, you check if `current` is a tail (last element) and then add your `nodeToInsert` to it. But then `data >= current.data` is redundant since `current.next == null` is sufficient to say whether an element is a tail or not. Hence:

```
if (current.next == null) {
    current.next = nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert.prev = current;
    break;
}
```

Or even here:

```
if (data >= current.data && data <= current.next.data) {
    DoublyLinkedListNode temp = current.next;
    current.next = nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert.prev = current;
    temp.prev = nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert.next = temp;
    break;
}
```

You can remove `data >= current.data` as it's given (initially `current = head` and so the check was made before the loop started):

```
if (data <= current.next.data) {
    DoublyLinkedListNode temp = current.next;
    current.next = nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert.prev = current;
    temp.prev = nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert.next = temp;
    break;
}
```

**Add useful comments**

You could've commented crucial blocks of your code better to make it easier to understand what you're doing. For instance:

```
// if current is the last element then add the new element after it
if (current.next == null) {
    current.next = nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert.prev = current;
    break;
}
```

Or

```
// if the new element is not greater than the next one 
// then insert it between the current element and the next one
if (data <= current.next.data) {
    DoublyLinkedListNode temp = current.next;
    current.next = nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert.prev = current;
    temp.prev = nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert.next = temp;
    break;
}
```

**Static method**

Well, I know, **Hackerrank** forces you to use the static `sortedInsert()` method so there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I take issue with is that all of this code is in a `static`. If you're already drinking the Java kool-aid, you can have a brief static wrapper to do your `if (head == null)` shortcut, but the rest of the code should be one or more methods on `DoublyLinkedListNode`. Rather than continuing to reference your parameter `data`, the instance saved to `nodeToInsert` would, in the method you write, access its `this.data`.

Overall the question asks you to do a thing that sucks, so it isn't your fault: sorted insertion to a linked list is O(n), but you can do much better with a different choice of data structure, such as an AVL tree. If you're interested, here's an [implementation of a sorted list in Java](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/12/22/sorted_lists_in_java.html).

Comment: Yes it's just a silly question. I'm already aware of AVL & RB trees. `static` was unfortunately there in the question.